# Java Clock Program

Tags: java, constructor, clock, accessor, mutators

I am trying to make a clock program using Java, and I got everything to work properly except I cannot get the program to change the negative values to 0. I also cannot get the program to set the values of hours, minutes, and seconds to 0 if they are out of range. I have a tester program that I have to use and the T1 and T2 clock values are incorrect in my code. T1 should be 0:0:0 and T2 should be 0:0:0 as well. However, when I output my code it comes out as T1 being -3:-21:-30 and T2 is 24:60:60. I know there is something wrong with my code, but I can't find the issue, if anyone would be able to help me that would be greatly appreciated. Below is my code and then the second section is the tester code that I have to use.

```
 public class Clock
 {
     // instance variables
     private int hours;
     private int minutes;
     private int seconds;

   public void setHours(int newHours) {
    hours = newHours;
    if (hours<0 || hours > 24) {
        hours = 0;
      }
   }
   public void setMinutes(int newMinutes) {
    minutes = newMinutes;
    if (minutes<0 || minutes > 60) {
        minutes = 0;
    }
   }
   public void setSeconds(int newSeconds) {
    seconds = newSeconds;
    if(seconds<0 || seconds > 60) {
        seconds = 0;
    }
    }

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Clock
 */
    public Clock(int newHour, int newMinute, int newSecond)
   {
    if (newHour > -1 || newHour < 24) {
        this.hours = newHour;
    }
    else {
        setHours(hours);
    }
    if (newMinute > -1 || newMinute < 60) {
        this.minutes = newMinute;
    }
    else {
        setMinutes(minutes);
    }
    if (newSecond > -1 || newSecond < 60) {
        this.seconds = newSecond;
    }
    else {
        setSeconds(seconds);
    }
}

public int getHours() {
    return hours;
}
public int getMinutes() {
    return minutes;
}
public int getSeconds() {
    return seconds;
}

public String toString() {
    return hours + ":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
}

public void tick() {
    seconds = seconds +1;
    if(seconds >= 60)
    {
        minutes ++;
        seconds = 0;
    }
    if(minutes >= 60)
    {
        hours++;
        minutes = 0;
    }
    if(hours >=24)
    {
        hours = 0;
    } 

}
```

}
The next piece is the tester code.

```
      public class ClockTest {
      public static void main(String [] args){

      //Create some clocks and print their times
      Clock c1 = new Clock(-3,-21,-30);
      System.out.println("T1: "+ c1);

      c1 = new Clock(24,60,60);
      System.out.println("T2: "+ c1);

      c1 = new Clock(3,21,30);
      System.out.println("T3: "+ c1);

      //Tick the clock twice and print its time
      c1.tick();
      c1.tick();
      System.out.println("T4: "+ c1);

      c1 = new Clock(3,30,59);
      c1.tick();
      System.out.println("T5: "+ c1);

       c1 = new Clock(3,59,59);
       c1.tick();
       System.out.println("T6: "+ c1);

       c1 = new Clock(23,59,59);
       c1.tick();
       System.out.println("T7: "+ c1);

       c1 = new Clock(0,0,1);
       c1.tick();
       System.out.println("T8: "+ c1);

       c1 = new Clock(1,1,1);
       c1.setHours(22);
       c1.setMinutes(30);
       c1.setSeconds(35);
       System.out.println("T9: "+ c1);       
       System.out.println("T10: " + c1.getHours() + ":"
                    +c1.getMinutes() + ":" + c1.getSeconds());
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Your condition is wrong. 
When you write this:

```
if (newHour > -1 || newHour < 24) {
```

You really mean this:

```
if (newHour > -1 && newHour < 24) {
```

Comment: I'd suggest `if (newHour >= 0 && newHour <= 23) ...` instead, as it better self-documents the exact range of valid hours. Similar for minutes and seconds as well (e.g., m >= 0 && m <= 59 instead of m > -1 && m < 60)

Comment: @KevinAnderson Okey Dokey. I think most developers are accustomed to the way you wrote it rather than the OP.

Answer (score 2):

@nicomp is correct and you should also be using >= 24 and 60 instead of >.  You might consider changing the constructor for Clock to

```
public Clock(int newHour, int newMinute, int newSecond) {
    setHours(newHour);
    setMinutes(newMinute);
    setSeconds(newSecond);
}
```

and then do all of your validation in the set methods, instead of having some validation in the set methods and some in the constructor.